# How to get an enumeration type from a string

Tags: vb.net, enums

In VB.NET I am looping through a list of names of enums (from a SQL table), to get the values for each enum object.  For instance,

enumerations.colors,

enumerations.sizes,

enumerations.patterns,

enumerations.unitOfMeasure,

etc.

```
Private Sub DoEnums() 
    Dim dt As DataTable = sqltodt("Select * from enums")
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim enumName As String = "enumerations." & dt.Rows(i).Item("enumName")
        Dim dte As DataTable = EnumToTable(Type.GetType(enumName))
        'do work here
    Next i
End Sub
```

I would expect `Type.GetType(enumName)` to return the enum object (ie, enumerations.color) but it returns nothing.

So how do I pass the enum name and get the enum object?

Comment: Without having done any testing, my first thought is that you need to make sure that you have fully qualified the type name and it may also be that the name is case-sensitive.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Enums aren't like other objects, you will struggle to have a generic enum object that can be typecast into a specific enum.

Comment: I use enumerations for static lists and reference the values in tables rather than the descriptions.  This is fine for just about everything except reporting.  In that case I need the text that goes with the value in the table.  The reports are drawing from SQL tables.  I could create a table for the enumeration for a specific report but this does not help the end-user who wants to create custom reports with the end-user report designer.  So the idea is to replicate the enumerations to a SQL table that can be used in SQL views for reporting.

Comment: And I have checked the casing and tried fully qualifying the type name.